# Does Shen carry targeted/delayed attacks when he ults?

Tags: league-of-legends

This is a question of how Shen ult works

If fizz shoots his shark at shen when he ults a weak ally does, the shark go with him and knockup him and his protected ally or does it just fizzle?

If Lee sin lands sonic wave on him and uses resonating strike, and Shen disappears while he is flying, does lee sin follow him or stop where he sonic striked?

Does Zilean bombs carry through the ultimate teleport?

I know that for most hit scan spells, do fly to target even if they leave range, i.e. Janna's Zephyr, I assume its same for Shen?

Comment: You should give a call to the Rift Myth's crew i guess. :)

Comment: Definitely check out Rift Myths, they cover the mechanics of many of these skills. For example, lee's sonic wave was covered in one episode, and wouldn't work, unless shen is still in a certain range.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

It all depends on timing for Lee Sin.  There is an infinitessimally small window of time for the former to happen, but it can.

Yes.

I don't quite understand your question.

Answer (score 1):

She will carry the shark through with his ult, there is actually a recent fail where he ults to a trist and kills her with the shark. 
I have no idea about the lee sin kick, it seems to do all sorts of random stuff when put in weird scenarios 
zil bombs will carry through the tele
you would have to test each spell individually because some will and some wont work with shen ult